# Pathfinding animation in phaser

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework, path-finding, 2d-games

So, I'm developing a small game in Phaser for the very first time.

The Idea is to move a character inside a dungeon using pathfinding (with easystar.js).

I used the source-code of this tutorial as a quick-starter:
https://www.dynetisgames.com/2018/03/06/pathfinding-easystar-phaser-3/

Here Pathfinding is functioning well but the character is constantly idling with no animations at all;
So I created this sprite with 4-way walking animation:

[image]

The idea was to attaching to each tween, used by easystar to create the path to follow, the correct animation, based on the position of the sprite compared to every tween; like this:

Attaching the animation to every tween:

```
Game.moveCharacter = function(path){
    // Sets up a list of tweens, one for each tile to walk, that will be chained by the timeline
    var tweens = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < path.length-1; i++){

        var ex = path[i+1].x;
        var ey = path[i+1].y;
        tweens.push({
            targets: Game.player,
            x: {value: ex*Game.map.tileWidth, duration: 200},
            y: {value: ey*Game.map.tileHeight, duration: 200},
            onUpdate: animatePath(ex*Game.map.tileWidth, ey*Game.map.tileHeight)           
        });                              
    }
    
    Game.scene.tweens.timeline({
        tweens: tweens,
        onComplete: stopAnimation
    });
};
```

Function for choosing the correct animation:

```
function animatePath(x, y)
{
    if(y < playerPosY)
    {
        playerPosY -= 32;
        console.log("up");
        Game.player.anims.play('up', true);
    }
    else if(y > playerPosY)
    {
        playerPosY += 32;
        console.log("down");
        Game.player.anims.play('down', true);
    }               
    else if(x < playerPosX)
    {
        playerPosX -= 32;
        console.log("left");
        Game.player.anims.play('left', true);
    }
    else if (x > playerPosX)
    {
        playerPosX += 32;
        console.log("right");
        Game.player.anims.play('right', true);
    }  
}
```

Where "32" is the dimension of each tile.

Function to stop the animation once the character is arrived:

```
function stopAnimation()
{
    Game.player.anims.stop(null, true);
}
```

Reading the logs, the path appears to be read correctly.
Problem is: the only animation that shows up is the one of the final tween, as if it overwrites all the others.
How can I force all animations to shows up?

Here's a video of what's going on

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6IUzv4BJG8&ab_channel=FrancescoPeruzzi